# have different events for different user groups

Tags: wordpress, civievent

I have users in different groups.depending on the group they are in when they see the events listing, I'd like them to only see events that are relevant to them based on the group(s) they are in.
For example, let's say I have users in 3 groups: Board member, Manager, employee. The board member gets to see events for all groups. The manager only gets to see manager events. The employee gets to see events for employee and manager.and also I'd like every group have their own calendar. 
(CiviCRM 4.7.25 on Wordpress 4.8?)

Comment: I guess you would have created a page to display all the events on the website. In the page try to look for logged in user permission and based on the user type alter the list. I am not sure about the calendar - Please wait for excepts you answer

Answer (score 1):

To restrict users to see events of their own group in CiviCRM UI then you will need to write an extension that will restrict this.

You can use CiviCRM hooks to restrict group to see their own events. Similarly in case of listing events on wordpress UI.

HTH

Pradeep